# Utility to encapsulate tail-call optimisation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming, tail-recursion

I've been reading about recursive functions and tail call optimisation (TCO) in JavaScript. My goal is to overcome the stack overflow in a recursive function:

```
function factorial(n) {
    function recur(n, acc) {
        if (n === 0) {
            return acc;
        } else {
            return recur(n - 1, n * acc);
        }
    }
    return recur(n, 1);
}

factorial(5); // 120
console.log(factorial(4585759)); // Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I have found how to use the `thunk` and `trampoline` to overcome the stack overflow in a recursive function:

```
let thunk = function (fn) {
    return function() {
        let args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);
        return function() { return fn.apply(this, args); };
    };
};

function trampoline(f) {
    while (f && f instanceof Function) {
        f = f();
    }
    return f;
}

function factorial(n) {
    let recur = function(x, n) {
        if (n === 0) {
            return x;
        } else {
            return thunk(recur)(n * x, n - 1);
        }
    };
    return trampoline(thunk(recur)(1, n));
}

console.log(factorial(5)); // 120
console.log(factorial(4585759)); // Infinity
```

However, I didn't like the way I'm forced to write the recursive function. I found some implementations of a function named `TCO`:

```
function tco(fn) {
  var active, nextArgs;
  return function() {
    var result;
    nextArgs = arguments;
    if (!active) {
      active = true;
      while (nextArgs) {
        result = fn.apply(this, [nextArgs, nextArgs = null][0]);
      }
      active = false;
    }
    return result;
  };
}
```

The function should allow the following:

```
let factorialToc = tco(function(n) {
    function recur(n, acc) {
        if (n === 0) {
            return acc;
        } else {
            return recur(n - 1, n * acc);
        }
    };
    return recur(n, 1);
});
```

But it is not working:

```
factorialToc(5); // 120
console.log(factorialToc(4585759)); // Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Is there any utility functions to encapsulate the TCO?

Comment: `return n * factorial(n - 1);` is *not* a tail call. You'll never get an optimisation with that.

Comment: I have updated the implementation of the factorial, should it work now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You applied that `tco` function to the non-recursive `factorialToc` function, not to `recur` that leads to your stack overflow. It should rather be

```
function factorialToc(n) {
    const recur = tco(function(n, acc) {
        if (n === 0) {
            return acc;
        } else {
            return recur(n - 1, n * acc);
        }
    });
    return recur(n, 1);
}
```